# Родительский элемент пуст если дочерный спозиционирован абсолютно

Tags: html, css

Собственно, проблема описана в названии темы. Есть родительский элемент с шириной, определённой в процентах и есть дочерний блок, у которого `position: absolute`. Так вот, родительский элемент отображается, как пустой, словно в нём и нет никакого контента. Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
    .parent {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 20%;
    }
    .parent .child {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    .parent .child a {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <a href="#">Some Button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: а как он должен показываться?

Comment: @Grundy хочу, чтобы он отображался, как `relative`-блок. Чтобы он был такого же размера, как и его дочерний элемент.

Answer (score 2):

Выставленное свойство `position: absolute` на элементе выбивает его/выводит элемент этот из потока документа/контекста форматирования. Что приводит к тому, что другие элементы отображаются на веб-странице так, словно абсолютно позиционированного элемента нет.

Вот и `div.parent` имеет высоту `0`, потому-что просто *не видит* дочерний.

Средствами `css` заставить родительский элемент реагировать на абсолютно спозиционированный дочерний у вас не получится. Можно разве что средствами `javascript` считывать размеры абсолютного элемента и применять их к родительскому.